# How can I get size (bytes) of a MongoDB collection with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Imagine I have a Mongoose model like this:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose')
Products = mongoose.model('Products')
```

How do I get size of the full corresponding collection in bytes? I found [`db.collection.storageSize`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.storageSize/), but it's nowhere to be found in the Mongoose API docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mongoose doesn't provide an abstraction for this, but you can access the native driver collection methods like [`stats()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#stats) from the [`collection`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-collection) property of a Mongoose Model. That method provides the collection's size as the `storageSize` property of the results:

```
Products.collection.stats(function(err, results) {
    console.log(results.storageSize);
});
```

Comment: what if I wanted to check the size of whole database, the situation is I have 500mb of free MongoDB hosting and I wanted to display on admin panel how much database is remaining and also genrate emails when reaching 90% to avoid any inconvenience because of database full, the answer could be "get all sizes of all collections one by one and then add" I understand but it would be more convenient if there is a way to get size of whole database at once, any help would be appriciated

Comment: Best to post that as a new question @InzamamMalik

Comment: const stats = await mongoose.connection.db.stats()

Answer (score 0):

```
var stats = Products.stats(function(err, stats) {
  // second parameter stats contains the result from  stats
  var storageSize = stats.storageSize;
});
```

gets statistics for `Products` collection.

Comment: Where did you get the `db` object using Mongoose?

Comment: Sorry, using Mongoose model you should be able to just use it... See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to use `.stats()` to get the storage size, the lib shows that the method `stats()` has been deprecated. The pipeline `$collstats` in aggregation is the correct way to acquire the data size in bytes.

[image]

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/collStats/

```js
db.collection.aggrate([{
 {
  $collStats:
    {
      // Kb=>scale=1024,...
      storageStats: { scale: <number> }, 
    }
 }
}])
```

[image]

The output will contain the `storageStats` like this

[image]